# Save complicated object without serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, machine-learning, deserialization

I would like to save this kind of object

```
public interface Politic<S, A> extends Serializable {

     public A computeAction(S state, A... autorizedActions);
}
```

At first, I used serializable for convenience, probleme is this inferface could depend on many other classes offtently modified, so I'm afraid I would not be able to deserialize.

Also, I can't simply use Json format because this interface depend on many parameters I can't know in advance. A politic is the result of a machine learning algorithm, and it is often a very complicated function I can't describe easily.

A typical politic would be like this

```
        Q<S, A, Double> q = (s, a) -> constructQ(s, a);
        Politic<S, A> pi = (s, autorizedActions) -> {
            return argmax(autorizedActions, s, q);
        };
```

where constructQ create a polynomial function (in this case it is quite simple, I just have to save coefficients of the polynomial function, but it could be something more complicated)

Comment: Do you mean you want a different serialization to Java serialization?  You can't save the data as bytes without some form of serialization.

Comment: In my case java serialization could be perfect but I'm not serialazing a straightforward bean,  I can't predict if my classes 'll be modified in the future. I would like to avoid any further problems of java deserialization. So I could use Json or other format, but a Politic is way too complicated to be described as just a list of key/value.

Comment: Would you also need Lambda serialization?

Comment: Yes that's part of the point, my politics is dynamically created

Comment: Note: serialized lambdas only deserialize if you have the same code.  You can generate the same code however, if you change the generated code too much, the lambdas won't deserialize.  This is because it doesn't serialize the code nor is there any library which can do this as the byte code of the lambdas is deliberately hidden.

Comment: Since you dynamically generate the classes you could save the source with object, this way it can always be deserialized after compiling the original code.

Comment: This is the solution I wanted to avoid, saving the source code, well at least I know I can't do better, thank you :)

Comment: If you don't save it yourself, you would need some even more clever way to reconstruct is such a way that the lambdas still work.  Saving the source is likely to be the simplest solution.